# What's the difference between .modal('show') and shown.bs.modal?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Calling a modal via Javascript, when do I use `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function())` and when to use `$('#myModal').modal('show')`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

```
.modal('show')
```

Manually opens a modal. Returns to the caller before the modal has actually been shown (i.e. before the `shown.bs.modal` event occurs).

---

Due to how HTML5 defines its semantics, the autofocus HTML attribute has no effect in Bootstrap modals. To achieve the same effect, use some custom JavaScript:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.